# Delay between inserting and deletion of index in azure search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I noticed that in the Azure Search, there is some delay after insertion and deletion.
For example in my code base there is method for inserting and method for deletion, after inserting index and delete does run, Even after that, document is still in index. After some time when i check it, it is gone.
And i couldn't find anything related about delay in azure spec. Has anyone have answer yet. Because I need proper proof that

Answer (score 2):

Yes, short delays are possible and common. For Azure Cognitive Search SDK tests we often [wait a second or two](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/5a03ed59743a5a2ed4f5efd71d1d8a7480651dea/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/tests/Samples/Sample05_IndexingDocuments.cs#L123) when updating an index before acting on and asserting code under test. The indexes are optimized for fast retrievals, but modifications may not always be immediate.